# Client side load balancing algorithm

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, ribbon, spring-cloud-loadbalancer

I have two microservices of B that's been replicated as B1 and B2, I want to send first 100 requests to microservice B1 and next 100 requests to microservice B2 from microservice A [Spring load balancer microservice application], So which client side load balancing algorithm is available to achieve this task.

Comment: That's not an algorithm that Spring Cloud provides. We provide `RoundRobinLoadBalancer` and `RandomLoadBalancer` and a number of ways of narrowing the service instance set that you can find described in the docs (We provide `RoundRobinLoadBalancer` and `RandomLoadBalancer` and a number of ways of narrowing the service instance set that you can find described in the docs (https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-commons/docs/current/reference/html/#spring-cloud-loadbalancer). You would need to implement on your own.

Comment: And then set up a custom configuration with your implementation (https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-commons/docs/current/reference/html/#custom-loadbalancer-configuration)